# Has the Force been used to destroy lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

This may be very rare, but in Legends, has someone used the Force to actually destroy their opponent's lightsaber?

Comment: It's not impossible. A lightsaber, after all, is just a mechanical contraption that depends on very precise construction at the molecular level via the Force in order to not explode on ignition. There's nothing about it that's indestructible with the right application of a Force Grip or Lightning. The bigger question however, is how to accomplish it without its Force-wielding owner noticing and stopping you, or why you would want to do that if said owner is dead or gone.

Comment: There was something close. In one of the earlier Clone Wars episodes where Yoda is leading a group of clones on Troydaria to convince the King to join the Republic, he stops Ventress mid-motion with the Force and then grabs her lightsabers right out of her hands with another Force pull. If he could do that, he could probably have also crushed them in her hands as well, rendering them useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

Ahsoka Tano once made a lightsaber explode with the Force. She may not have been *trying* to destroy it, but she was certainly trying to disable it.

> Sensing her intent at the last moment, the Inquisitor tried to disconnect his weapon and fight her with two blades instead of one, but it was spinning too quickly for him to do it. **Ahsoka’s hand landed almost gently on the cylindrical metal, and the Force was with her. The hilt cracked at her touch.**
>
> A sharp whine reached Ahsoka’s ears, the dark and light song of the crystals struggling for balance. She realized she needed to jump back even farther. She must have nicked the power connection that channeled the crystals inside his hilt, and now it was overloading. If he didn’t deactivate it soon, it was going to explode.
>
> Before she could even consider shouting a warning, **the red lightsaber burst into a mess of noise and light.** Bright spots pricked at her eyes, and then all was quiet. The creature wasn’t going to bother her anymore.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

One presumes, of course, that this is a difficult maneuver, one that depends on one’s opponent being sufficiently outclassed for one to touch their lightsaber, and not able to sufficiently defend their weapon using the Force (as would also be the case, for example), when grabbing an opponent’s lightsaber with the Force. It also seems that being able to touch the lightsaber makes things easier, so destroying a lightsaber from afar might be even harder.

Comment: She was helped by the fact that the Inquisitors were quite poorly trained, not used to facing trained Force users, and tended to rely upon the gadgetry of their spinning lightsabres rather than their own ability.

Comment: @Werrf - Precisely. She was a lot better than they were.

Comment: Worth noting that not only does this answer the question, but is fully canon. Well done.