# Has anyone ever used the Force to deactivate an opponent's lightsaber during combat?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, lightsaber

**Are there any canon sources of a person using the Force to deactivate an opponent's lightsaber during combat?**

There's [a question of whether a lightsaber even needs an activation button](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90522/why-did-most-lightsabers-have-an-activation-button?rq=1) because somebody could just use the Force to activate it. There's even a comment there about somebody using the Force to deactivate a weapon,

> If a lightsaber was only activated by the Force, how would that stop a Sith from deactivating a Jedi's lightsaber?

but as far as I can tell there's no question of deactivating one during combat as suggested by the comment above.

There's also [a question of using the Force to *power* a lightsaber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150142/powering-lightsabers-with-the-force-instead-of-a-switch?rq=1). (Different from activating one using the Force.)

And there's [a question about using the Force to destroy a lightsaber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137509/has-the-force-been-used-to-destroy-lightsabers).

But no question that I found about merely deactivating one to disarm an opponent. Seems like a fairly simple way to win a lightsaber duel. Has anyone done this during combat?

Comment: A very nice and well written question. Alas a dupe.

Comment: The previous question linked doesn't take into account The Last Jedi which was released after it was asked. Ren uses the force to summon Luke's lightsaber and at the same time activates it, slicing Snoke in half